# Embedding Code in Yacc

Tags: yacc, bison

I'm writing a yacc file as part of a compiler.
I have the following error:

```
lang_grammar.y:143.54-55: $2 of `ClassDeclaration' has no declared type
lang_grammar.y:143.69-70: $4 of `ClassDeclaration' has no declared type
lang_grammar.y:143.84-85: $6 of `ClassDeclaration' has no declared type
```

occurring on this line in my .y file:

```
CLASS { /* code will be embedded here */ } ID EXTENDS ID '{' ClassBody '}'
    { $$.classDeclaration = new ClassDeclaration($2.identifier, $4.identifier, $6.classBody); }
```

When I remove the inner embedded code:

```
CLASS ID EXTENDS ID '{' ClassBody '}'
    { $$.classDeclaration = new ClassDeclaration($2.identifier, $4.identifier, $6.classBody); }
```

It works just fine.

Are there limitations to embedding code within yacc? I was under the impression that this was possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have used wrong indexes. In previous way, embedded codes are also indexed, say

```
CLASS { /* code will be embedded here */ } ID EXTENDS ID '{' ClassBody '}'
$1    $2                                   $3 $4      $5 $6  $7        $8
```

So the action codes should be

```
{ $$.classDeclaration = new ClassDeclaration($3.identifier, $5.identifier, $7.classBody); }
```

Comment: ah, so the whole embedded section (from { to } ) counts for one index then